# How can I get dropdown selected value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net DropdownList Control.  when i use this code

```
var id = $("[id*='drpCategory'] option:selected").val();
```

the id is always come first index of dropdown. How can i get other selected values. ?

Comment: do you have 1 drop down that allows 1 value to be selected? multiple values? multiple drop downs?

Comment: The issue you're experiencing is that the selector is returning multiple elements. In your case the id variable now is a list of selected options that you have to loop through. Any of the answers below that use .each() will give you what you need.

Comment: Are you interested in which ID's have which values or are are you dealing with the case where you have multiple select elements that they can pick items from and it becomes a set?

Answer (score 3):

you can loop through the `select` elements, please note that using attribute selector alone is too slow, try this:

```
$("select[id*='drpCategory']").each(function(){
   alert(this.value)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var values = $("select[id*='drpCategory']").map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

and you will have the selected values of all `dropdown`s.

Comment: Love this approach. Perhaps do `"select[id*='drpCategory']"` since they `*=` selector is going to be costly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried but nothing change. When i selected the 3. item (third item value is 22), The Value is always come dropdowns's first item value (first item value is 2)  :s

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input_id").click(function(){
 var id = $("#drpCategory option:selected").val();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

jquerys `.val()` will return the selected value of your drop down, or an array of selected values if the drop down allows multiple.

```
var selectedItems = $('[id*="drpCategory"]').val();
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: please explain your downvotes. the OP specifically said "I have an asp.net DropdownList Control", singular, a single drop down, which this would work fine with.